# Terraform: use output of one module in another module

Tags: terraform

I have a module called vpc and another module called ecs. I'm trying to reference the AWS subnets created in the vpc module in ecs. Here's what I have, so far:

main.tf

```
module "ecs" {
  source = "./service/ecs"
  public_subnet_ids = module.vpc.ecs-public-subnet.ids
}
```

vpc.tf

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet-1" {
...
}
resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet-2" {
...
}
output "ecs-public-subnet" {
  value = [
    aws_subnet.public-subnet-1.id,
    aws_subnet.public-subnet-2.id
}
```

ecs.tf

```
variable "public_subnet_ids" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "public subnets"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
  ...
  network_configuration {
    ...
    subnets = ["${element(var.public_subnet_ids, count.index)}"]
```

When I execute plan, I get the following:

> Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context The "count" object
> can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only
> when the "count" argument is set.

Terraform version 1.1.8,
aws provider version 4.10.0

I'm totally happy with changing the entire approach, if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is used when you're using a block that's meant to make multiple resources. Think of it as like the index of a loop. What you're doing is simpler and easier - you're assigning an array to a field that takes an array.

First, just reference your array in the module definition. `.ids` is not valid:

```
module "ecs" {
  source = "./service/ecs"
  public_subnet_ids = module.vpc.ecs-public-subnet
}
```

Next, you can just reference the same array inside your module:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
  ...
  network_configuration {
    ...
    subnets = var.public_subnet_ids
```